# What's the error in the following code?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Here is my Django model

```
class author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name',max_length=140)
    datamode = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A', choices=DATAMODE_CHOICE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

While I use this class `author` as a foreign key in another class as follows:

```
class books(models.Model):
    NEW_FLAG=(('N','New'),('O','Old'))
    name = models.CharField('name',max_length=140)
    author = models.ForeignKey(author, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I enter the new book details in admin it shows:

```
IntegrityError: Column 'author_id' cannot be null.
```

Comment: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): _Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working i simply dropped my database and again i created a newone. Anyway thanks to everyone.

Comment: In future you can try to use django-south: http://south.aeracode.org/. This little app can helps you to find what tables(models) had changed and to migrate to new version.

Answer (score 6):

Just because your **model** says something does not mean that your **database** agrees. Verify your schema.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like you have changed you model. Have you used [`python manage.py syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) after changing your model?

If you are still *coding* your app and don't really care for keeping data, it could be better to delete data and have django creating tables again. If you have to keep data, then you'd have to verify your database schema, like it has been said.